# Python, running a loop on several CPUs

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I created a small code that works similar to sklearn gridsearch, It trains the model *(on X and y in the code below)* on one set of hyperparameters, checks the model performance using several metrics on validation data (*Xt, yt_class)* and stores the results in the pandas DataFrame.

```
    from sklearn.grid_search import ParameterGrid
    from sklearn.metrics import precision_score,f1_score

    grid = {'C':[1,10.0,50,100.0],'gamma':[0.00001,0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1]}
    param_grid = ParameterGrid(grid)
    results = pd.DataFrame(list(param_grid))
    precision = []
    f1 = []
    for params in param_grid:
        model = SVC(kernel='rbf',cache_size=1000,class_weight='balanced',**params)
        model.fit(X,y)
        precision.append(precision_score(yt_class, model.predict(Xt), average='weighted'))
        f1.append(f1_score(yt_class, model.predict(Xt), average='weighted'))
        print(params)
        print(precision_score(yt_class, model.predict(Xt), average='weighted'))
        print(f1_score(yt_class, model.predict(Xt), average='weighted'))

    results['precision'] = precision
    results['f1'] = f1
```

Now I am trying to make my loop run on several CPUs, I tried following basic examples for multiprocessing module, but being new to Python and programming overall wasn't able to figure out it works in my case.

Example of what does not work:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
pool = mp.Pool(processes=8)

def get_scores(param_grid):
    precision = []
    f1 = []
    for params in param_grid:
        model = SVC(kernel='rbf',cache_size=1000,class_weight='balanced',**params)
        model.fit(X,y)
        model.predict(Xt)
        precision.append(precision_score(yt_class, model.predict(Xt), average='weighted'))
        f1.append(f1_score(yt_class, model.predict(Xt), average='weighted'))
    return precision,f1    

scores = pool.apply(get_scores,param_grid)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `get_scores` method should only consist of the inner part of the loop

Try this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from sklearn.grid_search import ParameterGrid
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score,f1_score

def get_scores(params):
    model = SVC(kernel='rbf',cache_size=1000,class_weight='balanced',**params)
    model.fit(X,y)
    model.predict(Xt)
    precision = precision_score(yt_class, model.predict(Xt), average='weighted')
    f1 = f1_score(yt_class, model.predict(Xt), average='weighted')
    return precision, f1    


grid = {'C':[1,10.0,50,100.0],'gamma':[0.00001,0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1]}
param_grid = ParameterGrid(grid)
pool = mp.Pool(processes=8)

scores = pool.map_async(get_scores, param_grid).get()
# scores is a list of tuples [(precision_1, f1_1), (precision_2, f1_2)...]
# you can "unzip" it like this

precision, f1 = zip(*scores)
```

Comment: I get the following error after running the code (I get the same error after running my code as well): 'TypeError: get_scores() takes 1 positional argument but 20 were given'

Comment: Right, it should be map_async, not apply_async